# SpringBoot Passing parameter to CommandLineRunner

Tags: spring-boot, command-line-arguments

I'm using `SpringBoot 2.1.3` and I'm trying to passing a number of parameters through command line.

Here is the `main` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

@Value("${priceOne.pound}")
private Integer p1pound;

@Value("${priceOne.shilling}")
private Integer p1shilling;

@Value("${priceOne.pences}")
private Integer p1pences;

@Value("${priceTwo.pound}")
private Integer p2pound;

@Value("${priceTwo.shilling}")
private Integer p2shilling;

@Value("${priceTwo.pences}")
private Integer p2pences;

@Value("${factor}")
private Integer factor;

@Value("${op}")
private String op;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EurisApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    Price priceOne = new Price(p1pound, p1shilling, p1pences);
    Price priceTwo = new Price(p2pound, p2shilling, p2pences);
    ....
    ....
}
```

I tried to fill those variables with:

```
spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=--priceOne.pound=5, --priceOne.shilling=5, --priceOne.pences=5, --priceTwo.pound=5, --priceTwo.shilling=5, --priceTwo.pences=5, --factor=0, --op=+
```

or with:

```
spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--priceOne.pound=5, --priceOne.shilling=5, --priceOne.pences=5, --priceTwo.pound=5, --priceTwo.shilling=5, --priceTwo.pences=5, --factor=0, --op=+
```

if I add quotes `" "` at the beginning and at the end of the parameters list I obtain a conversion error..

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot.

---

Thanks for your replies!

if I remove all the parameters eccept the first and I launch the application with:

```
 spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--priceOne.pound=5
```

Works fine. Other ways you mentioned as:

```
 spring-boot:run --priceOne.pound=5
```

retrieve a parsing exception both with one parameter and with many. I'm a little bit confused..

it took me less time to write the whole application than to write that damned `commandLine` launch. I can't get all the parameters as a single `String`.. I don't understand why with just one parameter works and with two not!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As @improbable mentioned, `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments` is used to pass arguments to the `main()` method.

In order to set `@Value` attributes, directly use the `--` syntax:

```sh
spring-boot:run --priceOne.pound=5 --priceOne.shilling=5 --priceOne.pences=5, --priceTwo.pound=5 --priceTwo.shilling=5 --priceTwo.pences=5 --factor=0 --op=+
```

Please check the [relevant documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config)

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing [@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-value-annotations). It's used for injecting externalized properties.

If you don't have externalized properties that correspond - all these fields will be null.

Apart from that, in

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) {
```

`String... args` are your command line parameters in the form of varargs.

For instance, if you execute next line, you'll have varargs array that contains single element "first_arg_string", which is grabbed by index.

```
java -jar yourjar.jar "first_arg_string"
```

Answer (score -1):

Reading around (especially the **baldeung** docS) I found a solution to the problem **on my own** (lately it happens in 85% of cases, perhaps the forum has become too big..).

Then I post the solution hoping it will save time to somebody else. Now, considering the code above (which I propose again for clarity):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

@Value("${priceOne.pound}")
private Integer p1pound;

@Value("${priceOne.shilling}")
private Integer p1shilling;

@Value("${priceOne.pences}")
private Integer p1pences;

@Value("${priceTwo.pound}")
private Integer p2pound;

@Value("${priceTwo.shilling}")
private Integer p2shilling;

@Value("${priceTwo.pences}")
private Integer p2pences;

@Value("${factor}")
private Integer factor;

@Value("${op}")
private String op;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(EurisApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) {
 System.out.println(p1pound + " " + p1shilling + " " + p1pences + " " +
                    p2pound + " " + p2shilling + " " + p2pences + " " +
                    factor + " " + op;
}
```

If you want to launch the application with multiple parameters with `maven` or inside `Eclipse` using `maven launch configurator` (see picture below)

[image]

the string you have to use is:

```
spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.main.banner-mode=off,--priceOne.pound=5,--priceOne.shilling=5,--priceOne.pences=5,--priceTwo.pound=4,--priceTwo.shilling=4,--priceTwo.pences=4,--factor=5,--op=+
```

The String above will produce, according with the code inside `run()` method, the following output:

```
5 5 5 4 4 4 5 +
```

If you build the Application (with `Jar Packaging`) and want to launch it from `Terminal` (`cmd` in Windows for Example) you should use the following String:

```
java -jar [package_name].jar --priceOne.pound=5 --priceOne.shilling=5 --priceOne.pences=5 --priceTwo.pound=4 --priceTwo.shilling=4 --priceTwo.pences=4 --factor=5 --op=+
```

and it will produce the same result.

If you want to pass just one parameter you should use the following String with `maven`:

```
spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--priceOne.pound=5
```

And from `cmd`:

```
java -jar [package_name].jar --priceOne.pound=5
```

P.S.: These solutions work with `SpringBoot` ver >= `2.x`

Hope helps.